# Use EE Search Module to search custom fields

Tags: search, expressionengine, safecracker

I'm sure this is something simple for which I just haven't found the documentation:

I have a website with a member directory. All of the member data is stored in a members channel, which uses a variety of custom fields – some of which are part of the P&T Field Pack.

I use a Safecracker form to enter the data, and it renders the custom fields beautifully:

[image: P&T Fields Example 1]

[image: P&T Fields Example 1]

What I want is essentially the same form, but have it perform a search, instead of enter the field data.

I've scoured the Search Module documentation, but can't find information on how to search individual fields, let alone how to render them. I've also searched the Safecracker documentation for how to configure it to search (the ideal solution).

How do I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE's search module won't do what you want - it's more of a general search tool, and its "Advanced search" form is less about custom fields and more about things like channels and categories.

You want to look at Solspace's [Super Search](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/). It's much more powerful, and will allow you to do exactly what you want in terms of your query - though you will have to build the form manually (i.e., you won't get the SafeCracker-style simplicity of using `{field:field_name}` to have your form fields output for you).

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend checking out SuperSearch.